# "They always went to the bar." or "They would always go to the bar."

Tags: tense

I'm writing a story. I wanna tell that they(friends) were close and they used to go to the bar frequently. Should I say;

> They always went to the bar.

OR

> They would always go to the bar.

Comment: We don't give advice on style at this site, darkwolf. But if you expanded your example to give us a bit more context, and tell us which construction you would use, you may well get a helpful response.

Comment: hi i'm new here. i'd say they always went to the bar.  We don't need to use would right?

Comment: They always used to go to the bar = They would always go to the bar. it's DESCRIPTIVE. :)

Comment: i mean are they same meaing?

Comment: They mean the same, but in certain contexts one would be better than the other. To keep your story simple perhaps you should just say, "They always went to the bar." It is to do with *style*, as Ronald Sole suggested. Stories for young children don't use "used to" or '"would always".